# Redirect any non-existing page on domain, to Main Page WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I want to redirect any page that the user can type wrong to Main page.
Example:
I have pages
mydomain.com/home
And
mydomain.com/contact

any other pages i want to be redirected to Home.

I heard about 404.php and .htaccess files, but i don´t know how to make a simple redirect.

Comment: You have to read some tutorial about .htaccess and the try to code. On google you can find a lot of material about that.

Comment: Already made research on google, tried many options and examples, none of them worked, that's why i made a question on forum.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this into your .htaccess (place it into the web root if not present):

```
ErrorDocument 404  "insert home page (index.php)"
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html

Comment: at "insert home page" is the URL?

Comment: Its the path on your server, so i.e. /index.php